# sudden appearance of a non-specified border in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm kinda new to the whole website building and I just learned how to work with WordPress.
I've been building a site now for a few days on WordPress, when I was writing some CSS for the site without even using the color green in my code for the home page, I saw a green border appearing when I clicked on the shopping cart and the social media icons in the footer.
the green looks like the one I used for another page but it should not come up on my home page since I wrote CSS specific to each page, I even checked the code by inspecting but did not see that green color anywhere.
id love to hear your ideas.

btw this is my first ever question on stackoverflow. yay :)

Comment: You should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer.

Comment: It would be hard to tell without seeing an example (so called [mre]). But you can inspect the element which has the green border in the devtools and investigate where did the green come from

Comment: @O.Jones no, that is incorrect, questions about generic CSS issues like this get closed on WordPress stack exchange as they have nothing to do with WordPress and can be answered by anybody with frontend HTML/CSS knowledge, that their site is a WordPress site is coincidence

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it. I thought it is a border problem but apparently, it was just a color problem.
no idea why a border appeared but i wrote

```css
a:visited { color: transparent;}
```

and the border disappeared :/